# What is the meaning of "we are all one product or experience away from developing our own addictions"?

Tags: meaning

The main text is about gadget addiction. The author says:

> ... our understanding of addiction is too narrow. We tend to think of addiction as something inherent in certain people - those we label as addicts.......There isn't a bright line between addicts and the rest of us. **We are all one product or experience away from developing our own addictions.**
>
> — (*Irresistible: The Rise of Addictive Technology and the Business of Keeping Us Hooked* by Adam Alter, p.4)

Comment: It means we could all become addicted to the next product we buy or the next experience we undergo.

Comment: Which words do you not understand?  What do you find, when you consult a dictionary, which confuses you?

Comment: I could n't take the whole meaning of the sentence. But I took it with the help of  michael.hor257k and Simon B.

Comment: @hamed.Y, I answered your question below.  Was that helpful?  If so, consider editing your question, so that it will be taken off hold.  I thought it was a really interesting question.  All you'd have to do is say why you asked the question, what you didn't understand about it and whether you looked anything up.

Answer (score 0):

It means that the only difference between addicts and non-addicts is that the non-addicts have not yet tried the product or experience that they would become addicted to.

Answer (score 0):

Any device or process that stimulates the human brain can be considered addictive. While some people may be more prone to addiction, we all have the capacity to become addicted to the behavioral "high" of using electronic devices.

A 2012 journal article titled [Behavioral Addiction versus Substance Addiction: Correspondence of Psychiatric and Psychological Views](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3354400/) provides the following explanation of how an electronic device can be considered addictive.

> Behavioral science experts believe that all entities capable of
>   stimulating a person can be addictive; and whenever a habit changes
>   into an obligation, it can be considered as an addiction.

The same article provides these diagnostic criteria for addiction that may include behavioral addictions:

> A number of experts such as Brown have argued that the concept of
>   addiction is meaningful and that is should not be restricted to the
>   ingestion of substances. The six criteria of Brown can be
>   summarized as follows:
>
> 1. Salience: Domination of a person's life by the activity
> 2. Euphoria: A ‘buzz’ or a ‘high’ is derived from the activity
> 3. Tolerance: The activity has to be undertaken to a progressively 
>       greater extent to achieve the same ‘buzz’
> 4. Withdrawal Symptoms: Cessation of the activity leads to the occurrence
>       of unpleasant emotions or physical effects
> 5. Conflict: The activity leads to conflict with others or self-conflict
> 6. Relapse and Reinstatement: Resumption of the activity with the same
>       vigor subsequent to attempts to abstain, negative life consequences,
>      and negligence of job, educational or career opportunities.
>
> References:
>
> Brown RI. Some contributions of the study of gambling to the study of
>   other addictions. Gambling behavior and problem gambling. Reno, NV:
>   University of Nevada; 1993.
>
> Griffiths M. Behavioural addiction: An issue for everybody?
>   Pre-publication copy of an article published in Employee Counselling
>   Today. J Workplace. 1996
>
> Charlton JP. A factor-analytic investigation of computer ‘addiction’
>   and engagement. Br J Psychol. 2002;93:329–44.